# How to catch EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP CEdit Message?

Tags: c++, mfc, window, sendmessage, cedit

I'm trying to catch `CEdit EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP` message within `PreTranslateMessage` function.
Can somebody tell me how to do this ?
thank you

```
BOOL CTestDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if (pMsg->hwnd == m_edit1.GetSafeHwnd())
    {
        if (pMsg->message == EM_HIDEBALLOONTIP)
        {
        }
        
    }
    return CDialogEx::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to test that message without `pMsg->hwnd == m_edit1.GetSafeHwnd()` condition ?

Comment: I've already tried. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`PreTranslateMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#pretranslatemessage) is nested inside the message loop. Consequently, it is called for [queued messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues#queued-messages) only. [`EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-showballoontip) is a sent message, and never winds up in the message queue.

In other words: You cannot observe `EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP` in a `PreTranslateMessage` implementation.